# How to properly create root view controller in code in Xamarin.iOS with MvvmCross 6?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I'm trying to write Xamarin.iOS UI in code and I'm following [this MS tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/ios-code-only?tabs=vsmac). Unfortunately, I cannot work out the way to set my `MvxTabBarViewController` (`MainViewController`) as a root controller. Instantiating the controller results with NullReferenceException.

What is the proper way to set a controller as a root controller in MvvmCross?

---

My AppDelegate is as follows:

```cs
[Register(nameof(AppDelegate))]
public class AppDelegate : MvxApplicationDelegate<Setup, App>
{
    public override void FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application)
    {
        base.FinishedLaunching(application);
    }

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        var controller = new MainViewController();
        Window.RootViewController = controller;
        Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
        Debug.WriteLine("Set root view to MainViewController");
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the view controller to be root:

```cs
[MvxRootPresentation]
public partial class MainViewController : MvxTabBarViewController<MainViewModel>
{
    private UILabel label;
    //public MainViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    //{
    //}

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        Debug.WriteLine("Main View Controller loaded");
        AddLabel();
    }

    private void AddLabel()
    {
        label = new UILabel
        {
            Text = "testing",
            TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        };
        var lblConstraints = new[]
        {
            label.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(anchor:this.View.SafeAreaLayoutGuide.LeadingAnchor, constant:20.0f),
            label.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(label.IntrinsicContentSize.Width),
            label.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(anchor:this.View.SafeAreaLayoutGuide.TopAnchor, constant:20.0f),
            label.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(label.IntrinsicContentSize.Height)
            };
        View.AddSubview(label);
    }
}
```

The exception stacktrace:

```
  at MvvmCross.Mvx.Resolve[TService] () [0x00006] in <8a077b300d9c484ab0471c2d21c3cb26>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Platforms.Ios.Views.MvxBindingViewControllerAdapter..ctor (MvvmCross.Platforms.Ios.Views.Base.IMvxEventSourceViewController eventSource) [0x00034] in <8a077b300d9c484ab0471c2d21c3cb26>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Platforms.Ios.Views.MvxViewControllerAdaptingExtensions.AdaptForBinding (MvvmCross.Platforms.Ios.Views.Base.IMvxEventSourceViewController view) [0x00007] in <8a077b300d9c484ab0471c2d21c3cb26>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Platforms.Ios.Views.MvxBaseTabBarViewController..ctor () [0x00006] in <8a077b300d9c484ab0471c2d21c3cb26>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Platforms.Ios.Views.MvxTabBarViewController..ctor () [0x00000] in <8a077b300d9c484ab0471c2d21c3cb26>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Platforms.Ios.Views.MvxTabBarViewController`1[TViewModel]..ctor () [0x00000] in <8a077b300d9c484ab0471c2d21c3cb26>:0 
  at PushNotifTest.iOS.Views.Main.MainViewController..ctor () <0x13d7f4970 + 0x0004a> in <1d11ff58113e46f6a5a9245eccb8c13f>:0 
  at PushNotifTest.iOS.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (UIKit.UIApplication application, Foundation.NSDictionary launchOptions) [0x00017] in /Users/dominik/Projekty/PushNotifTest/src/PushNotifTest.iOS/AppDelegate.cs:28 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.11.0.280/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0002c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.11.0.280/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
  at PushNotifTest.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in /Users/dominik/Projekty/PushNotifTest/src/PushNotifTest.iOS/Main.cs:9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should let MvvmCross do that for you. Normally you would specify which ViewModel should be shown first in your `IMvxAppStart` derived class.

```cs
public class AppStart : IMvxAppStart
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;

    public AppStart(IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    public void Start(object hint = null)
    {
        try
        {
            _navigationService.Navigate<MainViewModel>().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Where `MainViewModel` would be the ViewModel associated to your ViewController which is the `MvxTabBarViewController`.

Then just do the regular ceremony in AppDelegate which MvvmCross expects you to:

```cs
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
    Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

    var setup = new Setup(this, Window);
    setup.Initialize();

    var startup = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
    startup.Start();

    Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

    return true;
}
```

So the `Setup` spins up the IoC container and other related MvvmCross services. Then your `IMvxAppStart` navigates to the first ViewController.

Depending on how you attribute your `MvxTabBarViewController`, it will be wrapped in a NavigationViewController. You can control it with the `MvxRootPresentationAttribute`.

```cs
[MvxRootPresentation(WrapInNavigationController = true)]
public partial class MainViewController : MvxTabBarViewController<MainViewModel>
```

EDIT:

Instead of doing the regular ceremony, MvvmCross 6.0 has made this part easier. So remove the body of the AppDelegate and create it like this instead:

```cs
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : MvxApplicationDelegate<MvxIosSetup<App>, App>
{
}
```

In your Core you then have a `App` class which implements `MvxApplication`. Here call `RegisterAppStart<TViewModel>()` in the `Initialize()` override:

```cs
public class App : MvxApplication
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        RegisterAppStart<RootViewModel>();
    }
```

Then don't create your own `AppStart` class. You can do UI Bound startup in `Startup()` in the `App` class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @cheesebaron! Would you also help me with handling two remaining interface members i.e. `void ResetStart()` and `bool IsStarted`? I cannot find any example with this version of the interface in MvvmCross repository.

Comment: Updated the answer :)

Comment: Would you be so kind to take a look at my source code or provide your own example? The main controller loads, but how should I populate tabs with views? I'm getting exception: `Default constructor not found for PushNotifTest.iOS.Views.Home.HomeViewController` while trying to navigate to HomeViewModel. Current source [can be found here](https://github.com/orestesgaolin/bottomnavview-xamarin-example/tree/develop).

Comment: Why did you add a ctor in the first place?

Comment: Oh, it was already there due to [MvxScaffolding](https://github.com/Plac3hold3r/MvxScaffolding). Removing it helped of course! I used `ShowInitialViewModelsCommand` from Playground app and the tabs are visible now. Thanks a lot!